# Copy a file from the RootSite to a SubSite

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-online, file-upload, rest

I'm trying to add a file from a Rootsite to a SubSite using REST API.

There some code:

```
$.ajax ( {
url : _spPageContextInfo.siteAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/getFileByServerRelativeUrl('" + selected + "')/$value",
        type : "GET",
        headers : { "Accept" : "application/json;odata=verbose" },
        binaryStringResponseBody : true
    } )
    .done ( function ( data ) {
        if ( data === null ) {
            console.error ( "The file wasn't downloaded" );
            return;
        }

        $.ajax ( {
                url : "https://dev.sharepoint.com/sites/myrootsite/_api/web/getFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/myrootsite/mysubsite/Lists/uploadeddocs')/Files/add(url='testFileUploaded.docx')",
                type : "POST",
                data : sdata,
                headers : {
                    "Accept" : "application/json;odata=verbose",
                    "X-RequestDigest" : $ ( "#__REQUESTDIGEST" ).val ( )
                }
            } )
            .done ( function ( ) { console.log ( "fuck yeah" ); } )
            .fail ( function ( ) { console.error ( "as usual" ); } );

    } );
```

but I always get the "File not found" error.

If I using the same code to create the file in the current rootsite it works.

Some ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is a typo in the url for the second endpoint. `getFolderByServerRelativeUrl` method expects the relative Url to be provided, for example:

```
http://<site url>/<web url>/_api/web/getFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/<web url>/<list name>/<folder name>')
```

or

```
http://<site url>/<web url>/_api/web/getFolderByServerRelativeUrl('<list name>/<folder name>')
```

In your case, if the target web url is `https://dev.sharepoint.com/sites/myrootsite/`, then you could specify the endpoint like this:

```
https://dev.sharepoint.com/sites/myrootsite/_api/web/getFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Lists/uploadeddocs')/Files/add(url='testFileUploaded.docx')
```

Comment: if you look at my code, the url parameter is there!

Comment: Please read the answer a bit carefully, i'm not saying that url parameter is missing or not. What i'm trying to tell that you are referencing web located here: https://dev.sharepoint.com/sites/myrootsite, but file location is: /sites/myrootsite/mysubsite/Lists/uploadeddocs, this is a different web. If you need to save a file at site https://dev.sharepoint.com/sites/myrootsite, then just try to replace in the second request the url parameter from the answer i've provided.

Comment: I think you missed the point... I'm trying to copy the file from the RootWeb to one of its SubSite.

So the file Location is on RootWeb/Lists/MyList/File (the GET call) then I trying to save that file to RootWeb/SubSite/Lists/MyList/

Comment: If you try to save a file into /sites/myrootsite/mysubsite/Lists/uploadeddocs, then try this url for the second request: https://dev.sharepoint.com/sites/myrootsite/mysubsite/_api/web/getFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Lists/uploadeddocs')/Files/add(url='testFileUploaded.docx') or https://dev.sharepoint.com/sites/myrootsite/mysubsite/_api/web/getFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/myrootsite/mysubsite/Lists/uploadeddocs')/Files/add(url='testFileUploaded.docx')  Pay attention, it is not the same as in your example.

Comment: Basically what i am still trying to tell you, in your example you are targeting web: https://dev.sharepoint.com/sites/myrootsite/ but at the same time specifying https://dev.sharepoint.com/sites/myrootsite/mysubsite/Lists/uploadeddocs for a file location, can you see it is a different sub site? You just need to target the correct web